# codeigniter pagination class : change seprator

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create pagination like example below, using codeigniter pagination library:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 .....
```

But when I look at config array in that library there is no option to do that. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$config['num_tag_open'] = ' | ';
$config['num_tag_close'] = ' | ';
```

Something like this. You'll have to play around with different tag configurations depending on how you have it set up, but the tag config options is what you're looking for.